# Error when trying to call js function in web view on Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, null, wkwebview

I am having a problem while I am in the middle of a web view.

The Web view looks normal, and there is no problem with the js function call that starts when you load the Web view.

The problem occurs when you try to call a function from somewhere else. We can't find the problem.

**Requesting a function**
**Other Screen.swift**

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myWebView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainWebViewController") as! mainWebViewController
                            myWebView.sendToCode(jsonString)
}
```

**WebView.Swift**

```swift
 @IBOutlet var mainWebView: WKWebView!
...

    func sendToCode(_ result : String) {
        mainWebView.evaluateJavaScript("calljsfunc(\(result))", completionHandler: { (any, err) -> Void in
            print(any ?? "no any")
            print(err ?? "no Error")
        })
    }
```

An error occurs in the 'mainWebView.evaluateJavaScript' section.

> Error is Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while
>   implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

[image: erros]

What is said to be nil

but I can get the result normally even if I don't add the result value, the error is the same. What's the problem? How can we fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly like error says, your web view is deallocated you can't access something that is no longer there. Did you try to set a breakpoint and try to print a webview? it is absent

Comment: Hi @Lu_ I've never set a break point.

Comment: so how do you debug your application?

Comment: @Lu_ When I  debugging, set breakpoints. However, this did not set a breakpoint, but an error occurred and the error was automatically positioned.

Comment: I just tell you that if you would try to know what happened you would find out that there is no webview and that is why it crashes

Comment: @Lu_ I'm running the function on the webview screen. Why can't I find a webview?

Comment: I don't see the rest of your code, can't help you with that little information

Comment: @Lu_  What's the code for the part you need?

Comment: If webview is not visible on a screen it will not work, it is deallocated right after you leave your DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: @Lu_  It is a different file that I execute the function, but the screen is a webview screen. Is it still nil? Then how can it not be nil?

Comment: if it is different I can't help you, I don't know your code, do you show that webview or not or whatt else do you do with it

Comment: @Lu_ Call up a function in a different screen file in the Web view. This will invoke the code function of the question on the other screen. And an error occurs.

Comment: So if it is a different screen your webview is not there so it is natural it will be NIL, you need to have this webview where you want to use it

Comment: @Lu_ So let's change the question. If I want to put a web view where I want to use it, what should I do?

Comment: add it to view controller where you want to use it

Comment: @Lu_ 'Other Screen.swift' is simply a file for function calls. An error occurs when calling a Web View function here.

Comment: exactly, you need a web VIEW in view controller, it is a view not a function caller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a view, not just a file for function calls, as the comment said. So I solved the problem by saving the current url value to the local storage and reloading the web view.

**Requesting a function Other Screen.swift**

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.callJsfunc()
}
    func callJsfunc() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let moveScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainWebViewController") as! mainWebViewController
        moveScreen.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        moveScreen.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = moveScreen
    }
```

**WebView.Swift**

```swift
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.sendToInAppCode(self.Result)
                self.Result = ""
            }
```